# Mispricing models for non-equity asset classes

Tags: equities, fixed-income, currency, commodities, c

Despite **risk**-factor models like [Fama/French
(1993)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304405X93900235) or q-theory based models like [Hou et al. (2015)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/28/3/650/1574802), others have proposed factor-models to capture **mispricing** in equities, e.g. [Stambaugh/Yuan (2017)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/30/4/1270/2965095) and [Daniel et al. (2020)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/33/4/1673/5522378). Even for non-equity markets, risk-models are developed like most recently even for cryptocurrencies ([Liu et al. (2022)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/jofi.13119)).

My research focus is equities, so i may have missed this in my literature review:

Do similar **mispricing** factor-models exist for other asset classes, namely the markets for bonds (fixed-income), commodities or currencies?